# Video is taking the full screen. not able to fix the size

Tags: dart, flutter

when I'm trying to embed a youtube video on my app page, the video is taking the full page and not showing the buttons. Can anyone please help me to fix the size of the video?

```
             Card(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    height: 8.0,

                    child: FlutterYoutube.playYoutubeVideoById(
                      apiKey: book.apiKey,
                      videoId: page.videoKey,
                      autoPlay: false, //default falase
                      fullScreen: false //default false
                    )
                ),
              ),

              Card(
                child: Container(
                  child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Card(
                              child: Container(
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                    child: Text('<< Previous'),
                                    onPressed: _gotoPreviousPage)
                              )
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
```